# How to create a boost::asio::buffer with uint8_t* [Is it possible?]

Tags: c++11, char, boost-asio, stdvector, uint8t

This question is about [boost::asio::buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/buffers.html)

I have a call to send data over a TCP socket. Following is the call:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data = GetDataToSend();
boost::asio::async_write(tcp_socket, boost::asio::buffer(data), 
    [this](const boost::system::error_code & error, std::size_t bytes_sent) {
        if (!error && bytes_sent > 0) {
            // Success!
        }
    });
```

Above is great as long as `GetDataToSend` returns a `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

**But**, what if `GetDataToSend` returned a `uint8_t*`? Isn't it possible to put the `uint8_t*` data into `boost::asio::buffer` and do an `async_write`? Something like below..

```
uint8_t* data = GetDataToSend();
boost::asio::async_write(tcp_socket, boost::asio::buffer(data), 
    [this](const boost::system::error_code & error, std::size_t bytes_sent) {
        if (!error && bytes_sent > 0) {
            // Success!
        }
    });
```

Is it that `boost::asio::buffer` only operates on `std::vector<unsigned char>`s?
How can I create a `boost::asio::buffer` object from `uint8_t*`? It will be great if I could do this without causing an extra copy if possible.

I am using boost 1.63.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [page](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html), there are all buffer overloads, one of them is

```
const_buffer buffer(
    const void * data,
    std::size_t size_in_bytes);
```

you could use it but you need to define the size of your buffer. Without this, how can `async_write` know how many bytes must be transmitted ? In case of `vector`, `buffer` knows this size by calling `vector::size` method. In case of raw buffers you have to provide this explicitly.

If `GetDataToSend` returned pair: pointer to data and its length, you could write:

```
std::pair<uint8_t*,size_t> GetDataToSend() {
   // ... 
   return result;  
}

std::pair<uint8_t*,int> data = GetDataToSend();
boost::asio::async_write(tcp_socket, boost::asio::buffer(data.first, data.second), ...
```